# Compare letter via a word

Tags: java

I don't understand my error: I have to compare a letter via a word for example `home`.

If the user enters the letter `o` a message must appear to inform that the letter `o` exists.

Else another message must appear to inform that the letter is not good.

My problem is that when I enter the letter `o`, I don't have the message that I have to get. 
Normally, the letter exists...

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
      System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
      char user_input_letter = enter.next().charAt(0);
      if(word_to_search.charAt(0) == user_input_letter){
        System.out.println("The letter exists !!");
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("This letter does not exist ! ");
      }
    }
```

Comment: all you need is just `"home".contains("o")`

Comment: `if(word_to_search.charAt(0) == user_input_letter)` you're only comparing with the first letter. Use `word_to_search.contains(user_input_letter)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below code. To find that characterssub contain by string or not.
Hope this will work for you.

> - code

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
    char user_input_letter = enter.next().charAt(0);
    if(word_to_search.indexOf(user_input_letter)>=0){
        System.out.println("The letter exists !!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("This letter does not exist ! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ton help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
     System.out.print("Enter your letter : ");
     char user_input_letter = enter.next().charAt(0);

     if(word_to_search.contains(user_input_letter+"")){
           System.out.println("The letter exists !!");
         }
     else{
    System.out.println("This letter does not exist ! ");
             }

    }
```